# Differentiation and simplification of composite function

Tags: calculus

in an introductory text on calculus for economists I found the following
$$ y=f(\bar{h}-t) $$
then, differentiating $y$ in respect to $t$
$$ \frac{dy}{dt}=f'(\bar{h}-t)\frac{d}{dt}(\bar{h}-t) $$
then simplifying
$$ \frac{dy}{dt}=-f'(\bar{h}-t) $$
While I think I understood the chain rule-based differentiation (derivative of outer function times inner function times derivative of inner function), I struggle to work out the simplification. 
Can please anyone be so patient to help with the simplification?
Thank you

Comment: This is correct. There is not a simplification, it just computed the derivative and treated $\overline y$ as a constant nothing more. WHich i dont know can be true :).

Comment: @hyprfrco You mean $\overline {h} $

Comment: yes!.. my mistake

Comment: Thank you very much. Now it makes sense, I got confused because the author said he was doing simplification.

Answer (score 0):

As you said, first you take the outer derivative, resulting in the prime notation. Then you take the inner derivative, which is equal to -1. Multiplying then together gives the result. It isn't simplified, just a slightly odd notation I think. Obviously, all this is assuming h is not a function of t.